# Can't update state after reloading the app in react native firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I have some issues with Firebase in React Native.

I'm tried to read the data from the Realtime database.
I get the data from database and set them into the state and my initial state is empty, like this

```
this.state = {
   providers: []
}
```

So now when I log the state in the console I see all of the data very well,

[image: First Time]

but when I go back to Home screen or reloading app then returns to the same screen I can't see any update in the state *Provider* and the console is clear that's mean the Array is **empty**,
[image: Func]

so what this does mean! I think the code is right?

Here is my Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import MapView, { Marker } from 'react-native-maps';
import firebase from "react-native-firebase";
// import * as turf from '@turf/turf';

import * as turf from "@turf/turf";

import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Dimensions, PermissionsAndroid, Image } from 'react-native';





let { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');
const LATITUDE = 50.78825;
const LONGITUDE = 40.4324;
const LATITUDE_DELTA = 0.0922;
const LONGITUDE_DELTA = 0.0421;

class Map extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            nearest: [],
            currentUser: null,
            error: null,
            width: width,
            marginBottom: 1,
            region: {
                longitude: LONGITUDE,
                latitude: LATITUDE,
                latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
                longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
            },
            providers: [],
            providerObj: [],
            distance: null,
        };

    }
    componentDidMount = () => {
        this.requestLocationPermission();
        this.handleProvider();
    };
    // Get All Provider in Db
    handleProvider = () => {
        console.log("The function is called but can't retrieve the data!");
        const providerRef = firebase.database().ref('providers');
        providerRef.once('value').then(snapshot => {
            // console.log(snapshot.val());
            console.log("TEST!!")
            let newState = [];
            snapshot.forEach(async (childSnapshot) => {
                console.log("The function is the data!");
                await newState.push({
                    id: childSnapshot.val().id,
                    username: childSnapshot.val().username,
                    coordinates: {
                        longitude: childSnapshot.val().coordinates.longitude,
                        latitude: childSnapshot.val().coordinates.latitude,
                    }
                });
            });
            this.setState({ providers: newState }, () => { this.handleNearby() })
        });
    }
    // first one of nearest provider
    handleNearby = () => {
        const { region, providers } = this.state;
        let points = providers.map(p => turf.point([p.coordinates.longitude, p.coordinates.latitude]));
        let collection = turf.featureCollection(points);
        let currentPoint = turf.point([region.longitude, region.latitude]);
        let nearestPoint = turf.nearestPoint(currentPoint, collection);
        // let addToMap = [currentPoint, points, nearestPoint];
        this.setState({ nearest: nearestPoint }, () => console.log(this.state.nearest));
        // console.log(Math.floor(nearest.properties.distanceToPoint));
        // console.log(addToMap);
    }
    // Get User Location
    requestLocationPermission = async () => {
        const LocationPermission = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
            PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            // , {
            //     'title': 'Location Access Required',
            //     'message': 'This App needs to Access your location'
            // }
        )
        if (LocationPermission === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
            //To Check, If Permission is granted
            await navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                //Will give you the current location
                position => {
                    const longitude = position.coords.longitude;
                    const latitude = position.coords.latitude;
                    this.setState({
                        ...this.state.region,
                        region: {
                            longitude,
                            latitude,
                            latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
                            longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
                        }
                    },
                        () => {
                            this.handleCurrentUserLocation();
                            // this.handleProvider();
                        }
                    );
                },
                error => console.log(error.message),
                { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 }
            );
            this.watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(position => {
                //Will give you the location on location change
                // console.log(position);
                //getting the Longitude from the location
                const longitude = position.coords.longitude;
                //getting the Latitude from the location
                const latitude = position.coords.latitude;
                //Setting state Latitude & Longitude to re re-render the Longitude Text
                // this.setState({
                //     region: {
                //         latitude,
                //         longitude,
                //         latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
                //         longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
                //     }
                this.setState({
                    ...this.state.region,
                    region: {
                        longitude,
                        latitude,
                        latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
                        longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
                    }
                }, () => this.handleCurrentUserLocation());
            });
        }

    }
    // Save own Location in database
    handleCurrentUserLocation = () => {
        const { region } = this.state;
        const currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        this.setState({ currentUser });
        firebase.database().ref("users/" + currentUser.uid).update({
            location: {
                longitude: region.longitude,
                latitude: region.latitude,
            }
        });

    }
    render() {

        // console.log(this.state.nearest.geometry.coordinates)
        const { region, providers } = this.state;
        return (
            <View style={styles.container} >
                <MapView
                    style={[styles.map, { width: this.state.width }]}
                    style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}
                    // onMapReady={() => console.log(this.state.region)}
                    showsUserLocation={true}
                    region={region}
                    loadingEnabled={true}
                    // style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}
                    textStyle={{ color: '#bc8b00' }}
                    containerStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'white', borderColor: '#BC8B00' }}
                >
                    <Marker
                        coordinate={region}
                        title="Hello"
                        description="description"
                        pinColor="navy"
                        // onPress={() => alert("Provider Profile")}
                        // icon={require('../assets/camera-icon.png')}
                        onCalloutPress={() => alert("Provider Profile")}
                    />
                    {this.state.providers.map((marker, index) => (<Marker key={index} coordinate={marker.coordinates} title={marker.username} />))}

                    {/* {this.state.nearest.map((marker, index) => (<Marker key={index} coordinate={marker.coordinates} title="f" />))} */}


                </MapView>
                {/* <Text>{this.state.region.latitude}</Text> */}
            </View>
        );

    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        padding: 30,
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    map: {
        position: 'absolute',
        zIndex: -1,
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        bottom: 0,
    },
});

export default Map;
```

Comment: It's easiest to help if you isolate the problem. Can you reproduce the problem without the map view? For example, it seems that the second screenshot only shows one item while the first screenshot shows multiple. Can you reproduce that behavior with only the database code and some logging statements, instead of a map. If so, it's much easier someone can help, since we don't have to consider a map view.

Comment: Alright, check now!

Comment: If you set a breakpoint on `this.setState({ providers: newState }` and run in a debugger, what is the value of `newState`?

Comment: Here is at the first time I run the app, https://imgur.com/Dd0kxXO, and here is the after reloading or close the app an reopen, https://imgur.com/uD7R3kd

Comment: In the second screenshot the debugger hasn't hit the breakpoint.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yup I don't know why he does that!!

Comment: So set a breakpoint in `componentDidMount` and see if that fires. If not, it seems the problem has little to do with Firebase, and it might be best to try and reproduce it with just react.

Comment: The same at second screenshot

Answer (score 1):

I think your database listener should look more like this:

```
const providerRef = firebase.database().ref('providers');
providerRef.on('value', snapshot => {
    var newState = [];
    console.log(snapshot.val());
    snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
        newState.push({
            id: childSnapshot.val().id,
            username: childSnapshot.val().username,
            coordinates: {
                longitude: childSnapshot.val().coordinates.longitude,
                latitude: childSnapshot.val().coordinates.latitude,
            }
        });
    });
    this.setState({ providers: newState })
});
```

Changes from yours:

- Declare `newState` *inside* the callback, so that you start out with an empty array each time you get data from Firebase.
- Call `setState(...)` only after processing *all* data from the database, instead of after each item.

Comment: sadly didn't work, the function calls just Once I don't know why! after reloading the app array is empty []

Comment: If this doesn't work, please do what I asked for in my comment to your question: Isolate the problem.