# Get All Element In Array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, geojson

I have some stuck with turfJs,

I want to get all the elements of parent array,
and set them into **FeatureCollection** I do iteration to all the array and get them isolated,
but when passing them to FeatureCollection they take just the last one not all,
so how to do that?

here is my Array "Users"

[image: Array]

and here is featureCollection

[image: featureCollection]

Function

```
 handleNearby = () => {
        const { region, providers } = this.state;
        let points = [];
        providers.map((p, i) => {
            console.log(p.coordinates);
            console.log(i);
            points = turf.point([p.coordinates.latitude, p.coordinates.longitude])
            // console.log(points);
        });
        var collection = turf.featureCollection([points]);
        console.log(collection);
        console.log(providers);
        // var targetPoint = turf.point([region.longitude, region.latitude]);
        // var nearest = turf.nearestPoint(targetPoint, points);
        // var addToMap = [targetPoint, points, nearest];
    }
```

Comment: Giving a minimal and testable example will help you get an answer much faster: 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

It's always a sign something's gone wrong if you use `map` on an array and you don't use the return value. The only purpose `map` serves is to go through an array and produce a *new* array of values created by mapping the old array's values to new values.

It sounds like you want an array of points, each point corresponding to an entry from `providers`. So map each provider to a point, and use the resulting array:

```
let points = providers.map(p => {
    return turf.point([p.coordinates.latitude, p.coordinates.longitude])
});
var collection = turf.featureCollection(points);
// Note no [] --------------------------^-----^
```

or with a concise arrow function:

```
let points = providers.map(p => turf.point([p.coordinates.latitude, p.coordinates.longitude]));
var collection = turf.featureCollection(points);
```

Comment: If you have time, can you check this Q?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55890775/cant-update-state-after-reloading-the-app-in-react-native-firebase